# Compare bytes in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I get data over TCP and try to compare it with a known value (0xAD):

```
b, addr = sock.recvfrom(1)
h = "".join(hex(ord(i)) for i in b)
print h
if h == str(0xad):
    print "Work"
    data = bytearray()
    data.append(observer.OBSERVER_VALIDATION_BYTE)
    sock.sendto(data, 0, addr)
```

I tried to compare them like strings as it shown above and tried to compare them like bytes in two ways:

```
b[0] == 0xAD
```

or

```
b2 = bytearray()
b2.append(0xAD)
b2[0] == b[0]
```

And all of the comparisons failed, though. `print h` gives me `0xad`.

I have a set of bytes defined like `BYTE = 0xAD`.
I need to send them over TCP and compare the read result.

If I define them like strings (`BYTE = '0xAD'`), it provides an ability to compare, but I can't put them in the bytearray to send because `bytearr.append(BYTE)` reasonably returns an error. So I can't redefine them as strings. So what is the way to compare `bytes` got from `sock.recvfrom` and value declared in the way I have?

Comment: Try `print(repr(h))` and then copy & paste that output to do the comparison.

Comment: @Bakuriu yep, it works. But what if I have all needed bytes defined not as strings but like `BYTE = 0xAD`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your problem is casting, you can cast variable *BYTES* to a bytearray this way:

```
>>> BYTE = '0xAD'
>>> ba = bytearray([int(BYTE, 16)])
```

Then compare bytearrays using `==`.